# Ошибка сors при использовании new XMLHttpRequest() с добавлением заголовков

Tags: javascript, http, cors, xmlhttprequest

При POST запросе на API в заголовке "Content-Type" не application/json а text/plain, при этом заголовки ставятся автоматически

При установке нужного заголовка вручную:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open(method, url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send();
```

Получаю ошибку CORS, в firefox показывает еще "СORS Missing Allow Origin"
Ставил заголовок "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", та же ошибка
На API к слову установлено "*"

Что ещё может быть не так ?

Comment: А какой смысл в этом заголовке если вы всё равно ничего не отправляете?

Comment: Оправляю, просто здесь не указал

Answer (score 0):

Заработало с настройками '*' при отключении credentials в сors на api (API NestJS)